# Do not understand this type definition in a valid JSON Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

For the definitions of `Cats` and `Dogs` in:

```
{
  "Boxes": {
        "type":"object",
        "properties":   {
                        "Cats": {"type":["integer","null"]},
                        "Dogs": {"type":["integer","null"]}
                        }
        }
}
```

What restraints does `"type": [ "integer", "null" ]` impose?

The following JSON validates against this schema: `{ "Boxes": { "Cats": [2, 3, 4, null, "hi"] } }`. Since `Cats` contains an array which in turn contains ints, strings and null, I would have assumed that the validation would have failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you want your data to have a top-level property named `"Boxes"`, then you need to define the top-level data to be an object with that property, e.g.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Boxes": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "Cats": {"type":["integer","null"]},
                "Dogs": {"type":["integer","null"]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the schema you've written, the top-level `"Boxes"` is ignored because it's not a keyword, so the schema effectively has no constraints at all.

If you used the above construction, then the `"Cats"` and `"Dogs"` properties would be constrained to be either an integer or `null`.

Arrays would not be allowed - if you want an array then you should define `"type":"array"` for these properties and then constrain the array items using `items`.

Comment: Thanks, however this does not answer my question of what the array in the type declaration does! Or are you saying the validation would have failed if I had the object declaration for Boxes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying - I'll amend the answer accordingly.